# How to send a base64 image to node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64

I know how to retrieve the base64 image from the canvas using javascript on the HTML page:

```
var url =  canvas.toDataURL("image/png");   
url.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
```

now i want to send this information to the server and create the image.
i want to do something like:

```
router.post('/createImage', function (req, res) {

    var base64image = //i need to get the base64 image here 
    var picPath = path.normalize('./public/images/users/pic.png');

    fs.writeFile(picPath, url, 'base64', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

how can i do that?